# Counting the number of binary partitions of k elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have a k elements which I'd like to partition in two groups.
Those two groups will be used for decision tree, where each branch is subsequently evaluated.

I have a textbook that says the number of cases is $$2^{k-1}-1$$ and I am trying to have an explanation for this number.

My ad-hoc explanation is that  $$2^{k-1}-1 = \frac{1}{2} (2^k-2)$$, which correspond to the number of subsets of k elements, minus the empty subset and the complete subset, divided by 2 as a subset or its complement yield the same split in 2 groups.

This explanation feels a bit ad-hoc though.
Is there a more general way of approaching these kind of question ?

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a perfectly good explanation.  Another (equivalent) way of looking at it is to label each of the elements as either belonging to the same subset as the first element or not.  There are $2^{k-1}$ ways of doing this (we know the label on the first element), and we discount the case where every element is in the same subset, so there are $2^{k-1}-1$ partitions into exactly two subsets.

Comment: interesting equivalent perspective. I was looking for it as well. I wonder if there is not a more radically different interpretation. for instance geometrical : this is the number of separating hyperplanes in R^k